# Where are the 'fresh-installation' config file of bind 9?

Tags: bind, debian-wheezy

Only for personal educational purpose, i've installed bind9 into a clean fresh-installed debian 7.1

Before start to study my 'pro dns and bind' book, i'd like to copy all of original config file of bind 9 to keep it apart, and to do more sarches about goal and meaning of each file and each row content.

Ok probably it's not the right way, but .. the question now is simply this:
where are ALL of bind 9 config file ?

Comment: Your question isn't a bad one, but it is off-topic for Server Fault (it does not relate to a system you manage [**in a professional capacity**](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: Wow, too stupid to be here . .  . Stack Overflow told me to ask here ... I'll go back to uselessgeek.com .... :)

Comment: Your question is not stupid (it's "basic", but that's OK - everyone starts somewhere) - it's even a good question (reasonable scoped, answerable) and you're going about the learning process the right way. Its only real flaw is it fails the "Professional Capacity" test (which I'll admit we used to allow more slack on, but if you look at the sort of questions we're getting asked lately it becomes obvious why we've tightened up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the contents of any official Debian package at http://packages.debian.org -- just select the correct release, package and architecture.

For bind9, AMD64, we see [the following configuration files](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/bind9/filelist):

AppArmor config

```
/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named
```

Bind zone configs

```
/etc/bind/bind.keys
/etc/bind/db.0
/etc/bind/db.127
/etc/bind/db.255
/etc/bind/db.empty
/etc/bind/db.local
/etc/bind/db.root
/etc/bind/named.conf
/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones
/etc/bind/named.conf.local
/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918
```

Service start/stop config

```
/etc/init.d/bind9
```

Interface state action configs

```
/etc/network/if-down.d/bind9
/etc/network/if-up.d/bind9
/etc/ppp/ip-down.d/bind9
/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/bind9
```

Firewall configuration

```
/etc/ufw/applications.d/bind9
```

Comment: and which of these are for config ? I want to esclude binary / readme / etc.. files

Comment: All of the files listed above are plain-text configuration files for `bind`.  If you follow [the package file list link](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/bind9/filelist) above, you'll see the binaries are under `/usr/sbin` and `/usr/share`.

Comment: If you're only looking for the files related to zones and bind behavior, proper, look at the files in `/etc/bind` above.